# Map of functions: The type of the function literal can't be inferred because the literal has a block as its body

Tags: dictionary, dart, warnings

How do I get rid of that warning in the following code?

```
final x = {
  'a': (Map param) {
    print('qwe');
  },
  'b': 0,
};
```

Dart version: 2.8.3.

Warning screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with the code you gave.  Where are you getting the warning from?  What version of Dart are you using?  Can you provide a complete example that can reproduce it?  I would *guess* that you could resolve your problem by explicitly specifying types instead of relying on inference: `final x = <String, int Function(Map<K, V>)>{ 'a': (param) { return param.length; } };` for whatever `K` and `V` are.

Comment: @jamesdlin New Flutter app in Android studio. Updated the example above, showing that explicit typing is not an option.

Comment: If your `Map` has heterogenous values, then it should be just `<String, dynamic>{...}`, and that should suppress all type-checking and lints.  Of course, you then would be responsible for ensuring that the types of the values are what you expect when you access them later.

Answer (score 0):

Use an arrow function.

```
final x = {
  'a': (Map param) => param.length
};
```

Comment: Sorry, I need a function body here

Comment: Arrow function? In Dart, this is called a function expression.